# Creating a linked list, templated Stack

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile the code my instructor has given us (had to retype it, but I can't find any typos) and it will not compile. We will be using this code for later assignments so I want to make it work before we get there.

It should simply make a linked-list based stack. I understand how the code works, and I have done templates before, but I can't figure out why it won't compile.

First Stack.h

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H
//Stack definition file
//Stack.h



template<class ItemType>
struct NodeType<ItemType>; //Line 9



template<class ItemType>
class StackType {
public:
    StackType();
    ~StackType();
    void MakeEmpty();
    void Push(ItemType);
    void Pop(ItemType &);
    bool IsEmpty() const;
    bool IsFull() const;
    ItemType Top();

private:
    NodeType* topPtr;
};


template<class ItemType>
struct NodeType<ItemType> {
    int info;
    NodeType<ItemType>* next;
}; //Line 34

#include "Stack.cpp"

#endif
```

Stack.cpp

```
//Stack implemenation
#include <iostream>

template<class ItemType>
StackType<ItemType>::StackType() { //Line 5
    topPtr=NULL;
}


template <class ItemType>
StackType<ItemType>::~StackType() { //Line 11
    MakeEmpty();
}



template <class ItemType>
void StackType<ItemType>::MakeEmpty() {
    NodeType<ItemType>* tempPtr;

    while (topPtr != NULL) {
        tempPtr = topPtr;
        topPtr = topPtr->next;
        delete tempPtr;
    }
}

template <class ItemType>
void StackType<ItemType>::Pop(ItemType & item) {

    NodeType<ItemType>* tempPtr;
    item = topPtr->info;
    tempPtr = topPtr;
    topPtr = topPtr->next;
    delete tempPtr;
}

template<class ItemType>
void StackType<ItemType>::Push(ItemType item) {
    NodeType<ItemType>* location;
    location = new NodeType<ItemType>;
    location->info = newItem;
    location->next = topPtr;
    topPtr = location;
}

template <class ItemType>
bool StackType<ItemType>::IsEmpty() const {
    return (topPtr=NULL);
}

template <class ItemType>
bool StackType<ItemType>::IsFull() const {
    return (false);
}

template<class ItemType>
ItemType StackType<ItemType>::Top() {
        return topPtr->info;
}
```

and main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Stack.h"
using namespace std;

int main () {

    int whatever;
    StackType<int> s;
    s.Push(10);
    s.Push(1);
    s.Pop(whatever);
    return 0;

}
```

The errors I get are

> c:\users\geldhart\dropbox\cs210\stack\stack.h(9): 
>     error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>   c:\users\geldhart\dropbox\cs210\stack\stack.h(9): 
>     error C2059: syntax error : '<'
>   c:\users\geldhart\dropbox\cs210\stack\stack.h(34): 
>     error C2753: 'NodeType' : partial specialization cannot match argument list for primary template
>    Stack.cpp
>   c:\users\geldhart\dropbox\cs210\stack\stack.cpp(5): 
>     error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>   c:\users\geldhart\dropbox\cs210\stack\stack.cpp(5): 
>     error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>   c:\users\geldhart\dropbox\cs210\stack\stack.cpp(5): 
>     error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
>   c:\users\geldhart\dropbox\cs210\stack\stack.cpp(5): 
>     error C2059: syntax error : '<'
>   c:\users\geldhart\dropbox\cs210\stack\stack.cpp(11):
>     error C2588: '::~StackType' : illegal global destructor
>   c:\users\geldhart\dropbox\cs210\stack\stack.cpp(11): 
>     fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation

Comment: Stack.h: `#include "Stack.cpp"` - are you sure about that?

Comment: @smocking: It's sort of OK, as `Stack.cpp` only contains template code. I would have called it `Stack.impl` or something like that, but that's just me.

Comment: @smocking it's actually required for template code, Every cpp file that includes that header has to include the cpp file that implements the template as well, as templates are converted by the compiler.  I also agree with the style design of using .impl

Answer (score 3):

This syntax

```
template<class ItemType>
struct NodeType<ItemType>; //Line 9
```

would possibly be for partially specializing some existing `NodeType`.

To (forward) declare the type, you just need

```
template<class ItemType>
struct NodeType;
```

Comment: There's a similar problem where the struct is defined at the foot of Stack.h

Comment: and several times in Stack.cpp.  It reads like someone was trying to convert java generics to c++ templates, the only time you can include<ItemType> after the class or struct label is if ItemType is the identifier of another class for which you want to specialize your struct or class.

Comment: Thanks, I now have it working, I found a few other problems, and now have it working.

Lesson: The professor isn't always right.